# Failing to compile/build: TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, node-sass, sass-loader

I've reviewed other responses to this issue, but this seems more complicated. My package.json has my loaders and webpack set up as follows:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "14.17.4",
    "npm": "6.14.14"
},


"dependencies": {
    ...
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
},

"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "prettier": "^2.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0"
  },
```

All the other answers to this issue revolve around version incompatibility, however these versions appear to be compatible. Any insight on this would be highly appreciated, thank you!

Full error:

```
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! web-frontend@0.1.0 build: `node --inspect scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Comment: node version and full stack trace?

Comment: What about `node-sass`?

Comment: Updated my post with additional information.

Comment: Let’s see `npm ls webpack`

Comment: `└── webpack@5.85.1 `

Comment: That doesn’t look complete. I’m out.

Comment: Why not? These configs haven't been changed in a while and this only started happening recently after I recloned the repo locally.